# How to Query/Update a Namely Profile using their API with Python

Tags: python, api

Hi I need to know how I can update a Namely profile using their API and python.

Comment: why it look like a promotion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short script on how to query a namely profile using their email so that you can get their id and update their phone number.

```
import requests
import json

accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

#headers for namely call
headers = {
    'authorization':'Bearer ' + accessToken, 
    'content-type':'application/json'
    }
    
email = 'testperson@company.com' #email to query
phoneNumber = '(123) 456-7890' #phone number to set

#get namely id based off email
namelyId = '' 
url = 'https://company.namely.com/api/v1/profiles.json?filter[email]=' + email
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    try:
        namelyId = res['profiles'][0]['id']
    except:
        #no results returned, means I couldn't find them
        print('Could not find a user with namely email: ' + email)
        quit()

#run update on Namley profile to update phone
url = 'https://company.namely.com/api/v1/profiles/' + namelyId +'.json'
data = {"profiles": [{"office_phone": phoneNumber}]}
res = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

print(res.status_code) #200 is success
```

Namely has pretty good documentation of how to use their api here: https://developers.namely.com/